# What makes up a Radiant Mafia?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, party

I get that the general point of it is that it's a party that focuses on Radiant damage and is apparently supposed to have a pretty high damage output, but which elements are needed to make it really powerful?

Answer (score 6):

#### Step 1: Inflict radiant vulnerability

There's no point in everyone focusing on radiant damage if enemies aren't vulnerable to radiant damage. So *make* them vulnerable. The Morninglord paragon path from the Forgotten Realms Player's Guide is the preferred choice for this (its level 16 ability gives any foe you hit with a radiant power vulnerability 10 to radiant damage until the end of your next turn). There are a variety of other options, though, including some paragon-tier items and epic-tier feats.

#### Step 2: Inflict radiant damage

Once the target is vulnerable to radiant damage, you hit it with as much radiant damage as possible. Multi-hit powers are preferred, since each hit benefits from the vulnerability. Playing a class that doesn't have radiant powers? No problem! There are several weapon enchantments that can convert your damage to radiant.

#### Step 2A: Or just deal any kind of damage

The Pervasive Light feat from Divine Power gives you bonus damage equal to a target's radiant vulnerability whenever you hit with an attack that doesn't deal radiant damage. It requires you to have a divine class but multi-classing can solve that problem for most characters.

<sub>(Note that most of the tricks that make Radiant Mafia work so well don't kick in until paragon tier; a heroic-tier Radiant Mafia party will play just like any other party, other than maybe being a bit heavier on divine characters.)</sub>

Comment: Is having multiple Morninglords in a party any useful? If not, are there any particular feats or other PPs/EDs that synergize well with one? And is there any particular role that the Morninglord should be, like Defender or Striker or whatever? (I'm mainly just wondering because I'm working on a Pal|Lock and was considering grabbing the Morninglord PP.)

Comment: @T.Smit More morninglords isn't necessary but certainly doesn't hurt; it increases the chances one will land a hit to inflict radiant vulnerability, and makes it easier to inflict vulnerability on multiple enemies. Morninglord works reasonably well for any role.

Comment: Would any of the switch builds (like killswitch) work well in one?

Comment: @T.Smit Switch builds work well with almost any party. The [lightswitch](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?471673-Lightswitch-Deva-Artificer-Cleric-Spell-Commander-Chosen-of-Ioun-by-Nausicaa&prefixid=wotc) build is probably the easiest to fit into Radiant Mafia, but any of the switches would probably work fine.